# Is it possible to automatically add default value?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to automate this function in MySQLi and how?

```
UPDATE `com_users` SET `avatar` = 'images/profiler/image.png' WHERE `avatar` = ''
```

This is my weird workaround to set up the default avatar for registered users, because I need to have a default avatar for guests and another default for registered.

Comment: May I ask: Are guests even present in the database?  Can you better explain what you mean by automate?

Comment: Hi! Sure! Guests doesn't present in database, but the component i use allow me to choose the default avatar which will be used for all users - guests, registered, admins etc, who didn't choose avatar. So this option i left for the guests, but i want registered users to have different default avatar. This is why i needed that answer by @dansimens below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could alter the table, such that the specified column has a `default` constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE com_users ALTER avatar SET DEFAULT 'images/profiler/image.png'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, @dansiemens,  tell me is it gonna work automagically all the time?

Comment: Whenever you insert data into com_users, if avatar is unspecified then it will default to 'images/profiler/image.png'. However, this will not take care of those entries which already exist in com_users, so you'll want to run an UPDATE query to take care of those.